# Is it good practice to use run function instead of return in Kotlin?

Tags: return, kotlin

Kotlin has an extension function `run`.

```
/**
 * Calls the specified function [block] and returns its result.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <R> run(block: () -> R): R = block()
```

And `run` function can be used instead of return.

```
// an example multi-line method using return
fun plus(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
  val sum = a + b
  return sum
}

// uses run instead of return
fun plus(a: Int, b: Int): Int = run {
  val sum = a + b
  sum
}
```

Which style is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For more complicated functions the first option will be more readable.
For simple functions I would suggest taking a look at [Single-expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) syntax.

```
fun plus(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
```